# ZSH Prompt/RPrompt Conflict

Tags: zsh, prompt

I currently have my ZSH PROMPT variable set up as:
`PROMPT=$'[%{\e[0;32m%}%n@%m:%~%{\e[0m%}]>`

and my RPROMPT variable as:
`RPROMPT=$'[%{\e[0;32m%}%T\e[0m%}]'`

The effect I'm working for is to make the brackets and ">" white (using Terminal text-color settings) and everything inside of those green. However, when RPrompt is enabled in OS X (Ubuntu works fine), text entry begins 3 characters INTO the LPrompt, and overwrites the last 3 characters!!

[Screenshot http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/4575/screenshot20091112at722.png](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/4575/screenshot20091112at722.png)

**What is the proper way to color my ZSH Prompt and RPrompt to avoid this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RPROMPT` messes up for me on Ubuntu. Since `zsh` knows ANSI color sequences and has its own facility for that (which automatically takes care of zero-width correction, too), try this:

```
RPROMPT='[%F{green}%T%f]'
```

And, by the way:

```
PROMPT='[%F{green}%n@%m:%~%f]>'
```

Comment: There's nothing in the PROMPT definition which warrants $'...' instead of just '...'; the $'...' form interprets echo/print escapes when setting the value of the string (and you're missing the trailing ' too, obviously).

Comment: Oops, I simply copied and pasted what was in the OP's question.